# C# - Viewing Datas From Different Table With Foreign Key And Show in Datagrid View

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, datagrid

I'm having a trouble how can I select the datas and execute them in the datagridview with the foreign key from different table?

This is the scenario

The name of my datagrid is

```
dgv_results
```

And my foreign key is

```
customer_id
```

Here's my select query on one particular table

```
Data dt = new Data // Data is my Connection .cs Form

public void MyFirstTable() {
        dt.Connection();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM firsttable WHERE customer_id='" + customer_id + "'", dt.connect);
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Load(dr);

        dgv_results.DataSource = table;
    }
```

Then I put the MyFirstTable on the Form Loan

Any help? Thank you guys!

Comment: Since you are new to this, you should start using SQLParameters from now, your code is not safe against sql injections.

Comment: This is just for C# Winform